# Проблема с linearGradient (SVG) в IOS устройствах

Tags: html, css, ios, svg

Два примера простых SVG с text элементом, textPath для создания дуги, а также установленным атрибутом textLength.

В первом случае, цвет текста изменяется при помощи заданного linearGradient.
Во втором случае, при помощи самого простого fill атрибута.

**Проблема с отображением первого примера** наблюдается на IOS устройствах (Iphone 12, Iphone XR, наверное и на других). Браузеры хром и сафари. Скриншоты прикладываю, обрезается текст в примере 1, в примере 2 все хорошо.

На десктопе в браузерах или на андроид устройствах проблема не наблюдается, попробовал порядка 5 разных устройств.

Вопрос - есть ли какое-то решение как поправить отображение цвета с градиентом на IOS устройствах? Причем как видно, в градиенте всего 1 цвет. Возможно есть какой-то css параметр или атрибут градиента, который это фиксит?

Пример 1.

```html
 ​<svg width="300px" height="300px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 400" color="red">
           ​<defs>
             ​<linearGradient id="fill">
               ​<stop stop-color="red"></stop>
             ​</linearGradient>
           ​</defs>
           ​<text font-size="28" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" fill="url(#fill)" transform="rotate(-11, 200, 200)" textLength="463.5587568803267"><defs><path id="text" d="M 200 200 m -168, 0 a 168,168 0 1,0 336,0 a 168,168 0 1,0 -336,0"></path></defs><textPath href="#text" xlink:href="#text" textLength="463.5587568803267">Пример текста по кругу</textPath></text>
           ​
         ​</svg>
```

Пример 2.

```html
​<svg width="300px" height="300px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 400" fill="red">
           ​<text font-size="28" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" transform="rotate(-11, 200, 200)" textLength="463.5587568803267"><defs><path id="text" d="M 200 200 m -168, 0 a 168,168 0 1,0 336,0 a 168,168 0 1,0 -336,0"></path></defs><textPath href="#text" xlink:href="#text" textLength="463.5587568803267">Пример текста по кругу</textPath></text>
</svg>
```

[Скриншот отображения примера 1 на IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdsOF.jpg)

[Скриншот отображения примера 2 на IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1mll.jpg)

[Скриншот примера от Alexandr_TT на IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fYHq.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### textLength

Теория -[textLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/textLength)

> Атрибут textLength, доступный для элементов SVG  и ,
> позволяет указать ширину пространства, в котором будет отображаться
> текст. Пользовательский агент будет следить за тем, чтобы текст не
> простирался дальше этого расстояния, используя метод или методы,
> указанные атрибутом lengthAdjust. По умолчанию регулируется только
> интервал между символами, но размер глифа также можно настроить, если
> изменить lengthAdjust.

На практике в разных браузерах текст масштабируется и позиционируется немного по разному. Например FF, Chrome и Safari. Настроив положение текста в одном браузере, в другом браузере текст может быть сдвинут.

Поэтому лучше отказаться от этого атрибута и заменить его на атрибуты CSS

```
letter-spacing: 4px;
word-spacing: 2px;
```

Которые работают одинаково во всех браузерах.

Изменяя значения этих атрибутов, а также `font-size`, `startOfset` можно достичь желаемого результата.

```css
#txt {
font-size:36px;
font-style:normal;
font-weight:normal;
fill:url(#fill);
letter-spacing: 4px;
word-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" width="300px" height="300px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
  ​<defs>
       ​<linearGradient id="fill">
               ​<stop offset ="0" stop-color="red"></stop>
                ​<stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"></stop>
       ​</linearGradient>
             <path id="text" stroke="black" fill="none" d="M 200 200 m -168, 0 a 168,168 0 1,
                     0 336,0 a 168,168 0 1,0 -336,0" /> 
  ​</defs>
   ​<text id="txt">
           <textPath href="#text" xlink:href="#text"  startOffset="3%">
              Пример текста по кругу  
           </textPath>
  </text> 
</svg>
```

### UPDATE

Добавил в градиент

`gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0"`

Изменил `path` для кривой, как-то он был странновато написан

`d="M 200 200 m -168, 0` ?? В качестве начальной точки есть дублирующая запись
абсолютных **M 200 200** и относительных координат - **m -168, 0**
может это причина бага Safari в IOS?

### Просьба:

У кого есть айфон с Safari, Chrome проверьте пожалуйста код ниже на предмет исчезновения крайних букв.

```css
#txt {
font-size:36px;
font-style:normal;
font-weight:normal;
fill:url(#fill);
letter-spacing: 4px;
word-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" width="300px" height="300px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border: 1px solid">
  ​<defs>
       ​<linearGradient id="fill" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="0">
               ​<stop offset ="0%" stop-color="red"></stop>
                ​<stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"></stop>
       ​</linearGradient>
              <path id="text" stroke="black" fill="none" d="M20,200  A180,180 0 1 0 380,200" />
  ​</defs>        ​<text id="txt">
           <textPath href="#text" xlink:href="#text"  startOffset="10%">
              Пример текста по кругу  
           </textPath>
        </text> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Это не помогает. Точно также обрезает первую и последнюю букву. Это определенно или баг или какая-то особенность. Обрезает 1 в 1 как в том скриншоте, что прикладывал до этого.

Comment: Баг именно в градиенте + тексте дугой, в этой связке. Если одно из двух убрать, то все будет корректно.

Comment: @Floyat Обновил ответ. **Проверь здесь прямо с айфона**, если здесь всё нормально, а у тебя в приложении обрезает, значит где-то баг у тебя в приложении, в вёрстке.

Comment: Обрезает последнюю букву "у". Видео https://disk.yandex.ru/i/OtA2sHPf2fjMvw Сафари https://disk.yandex.ru/i/ze0tfEo7LnqKUg Хром https://disk.yandex.ru/i/pWvf5B4TwtJZIw Я также вчера попросил знакомых проверить с 11-го айфона и SE. По итогу сейчас я выявил, что проблема есть на: SE, XR, 11, 12. Проверяли вот в этой теме или на codepen, куда я просто копировал примеры.

Comment: Также попробовал менять значения всех доступных атрибутов для градиента. Задавать различные значения x1, y1, x2, y2. Но эффект такой же. Также попробовал менять значение startOffset у textPath. 0% - https://disk.yandex.ru/i/TLKRdjGnpPMf9g 20% - https://disk.yandex.ru/i/imDimoHZc8snfw 50% - https://disk.yandex.ru/i/kKazvJh97HLgrg

Comment: @Floyat вероятно лучше оперировать не моделями телефонов, а версиями iOS, зачастую в зависимости от версии есть разница в отображении, и еще момент - все браузеры на iOS (сафари, хром и тд) используют один и тот же движок сафари, так что по идее если не работает в одном браузере, то вероятно не работает и во всех остальных при условии одинаковых системных требований

Comment: 15-я на всех, кроме старого SE. На нем 13-я. Что-то не могу припомнить других таких случаев, чтобы в зависимости от операционной системы или версии ОС по-разному движки браузеров отображали html. Тем более на последних версиях.

Comment: @Floyat Видимо это всё таки баг Safari IOS, который пока не представляется возможным устранить всяческими ухищрениями. Я практически всё перепробывал, что видно из ответов.  Выход, который и ты предлагал,- заменить градиент на закраску - fill="red" для текста, либо ждать, когда в следующем обновлении safari исправят баг.

Answer (score 1):

> Причем как видно, в градиенте всего 1 цвет

Вот в этом и есть главная причина. Кроме того упущен важный параметр `offset`

Если необходимо, чтобы было кросс браузерное решение, нужно задавать параметры [linearGradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients) в соответствии со спецификацией, указывая все атрибуты градиента:

```
<linearGradient id="fill">
               ​<stop offset ="0" stop-color="red"></stop>
                ​<stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"></stop>
             ​</linearGradient>
```

Ещё можно отметить, что текст на кривой нужно позиционировать не трансформацией вращения - `transform="rotate(-11, 200, 200)"`, а с помощью - [startOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/startOffset)

`color="red"`  - нужно убрать из шапки SVG. Зачем сразу красить весь блок svg в красный цвет. У вас этим, по идее должен заниматься градиент.
Иначе потом, можно долго искать причину, почему невозможно стилизовать файл из CSS/

```html
<svg width="300px" height="300px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
  ​<defs>
       ​<linearGradient id="fill">
               ​<stop offset ="0" stop-color="red"></stop>
                ​<stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"></stop>
       ​</linearGradient>
               <path id="text" stroke="black" d="M 200 200 m -168, 0 a 168,168 0 1,
                     0 336,0 a 168,168 0 1,0 -336,0"/>   
  ​</defs>
        ​<text font-size="36" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" fill="url(#fill)"  textLength="463.5587568803267">
           <textPath href="#text" xlink:href="#text" textLength="463.5587568803267" startOffset="2.5%">
              Пример текста по кругу 
           </textPath>
        </text>
</svg>
```

### Пример анимации текста

Используется изменение значений параметра `startOfset`

```
 <animate id="anT" attributeName="startOffset" begin="svg1.click;anT.end+0.5s"
  dur="4s" values="2.5%;100%" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" />
```

*Анимация начнётся  после клика*

```html
<svg id="svg1" width="300px" height="300px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 400" style="border:1px solid" >
  ​<defs>
       ​<linearGradient id="fill">
               ​<stop offset ="0" stop-color="red"></stop>
                ​<stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"></stop>
       ​</linearGradient>
               <path id="text" stroke="black" d="M 200 200 m -168, 0 a 168,168 0 1,
                     0 336,0 a 168,168 0 1,0 -336,0"/>   
  ​</defs>
        ​<text font-size="36" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" fill="url(#fill)"  textLength="463.5587568803267">
           <textPath href="#text" xlink:href="#text" textLength="463.5587568803267" startOffset="2.5%">
              Пример текста по кругу 
              <animate id="anT" attributeName="startOffset" begin="svg1.click;anT.end+0.5s" dur="4s" values="2.5%;100%" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" /> 
           </textPath>
        </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: В том то и проблема, что это не кроссбраузерное решение из-за айфонов. Я добавил в первое сообщение ссылку на скрин открытого вашего примера "анимации текста" на Iphone XR в сафари. В хроме аналогично. Чуть позже проверю на 12-м, но думаю будет точно также. Какой-то глобальный баг на айфонах. Как видно, первые и последние буквы некорректно обрезаются. При этом любые браузеры десктопные и андроид устройства отображают корректно, вот что меня больше всего удивило.

Comment: Также записал видео как в хроме на айфоне выглядит анимация. https://disk.yandex.ru/i/mK3R-Oa1Ivtcpg Съедает различные куски букв при прокрутке, как видно. И только на айфонах вот так.

Comment: @Floyat Сейчас сделаю второй ответ. Проверю вторую версию - причину бага. К сожалению у меня нет айфона, нет возможности проверить, поэтому прошу вас оперативно ответить. Если не получится, будем дальше искать.